# How to format json string in Python

Tags: python, json, string, format

I have a number of string with json format such as `'{"key1":{0}, "key2":{1}}'`.

After I retrieve the json string and substitute with values.
`'{"key1":{0}, "key2":{1}}'.format("value1", "value2")`. # `KeyError: '"key1"`

The problem is caused by the bracket `{`, and I should use `{{` and `}}` in the string, however, it is not easy to add `{` to the the string because the bracket may appear in the middle part such as `'{"key1":{0}, "key2":{1}, "{3}":"value3"}'`

How can I format the json string?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Format like any other string and then use `json.loads`

Comment: @MalikBrahimi His trouble is that the format function will think it's a formatting block when it's not.

Comment: Trying to perform string substitution into the JSON string is not Pythonic and is error-prone. Build the value as a dictionary instead and use `json.dumps`.

Comment: @Sean where are you getting these json to-be-formatted strings from? It would seem they need to provide a better format. The only way to handle this is to recognize that `{number}` is not a valid dictionary because it doesn't have any `:`'s in it.

Comment: @Sean Are you trying to create a json string on your own? If so do what Kupiakos is saying.

Comment: @CrazyCasta  I create the json string on my own because the json string is sotred in the Pandas table. I cannot store dictionary into a Pandas table cell, that is why I `json.dumps` to string to store into the pandas table cell, and later, I read the cell and do substitution.

Comment: @Sean, you could probably benefit from using a more suitable format for the problem.

Comment: @Sean so you just want two curly brackets and the beginning and end of the JSON string instead of one?

Comment: The example string you provide is not valid JSON.  Maybe your strings look something like this: `'{"key1":"{0}","key2":"{1}"}'`?  (Notice the quotes around the format parameters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to manipulate the data as an encoded string.  Decode the JSON before trying to apply the formatting.

```
import json

json_data = '{"key1":"{0}","key2":"{1}"}'
format_args = ["value1", "value2"]

data = json.loads(json_data)
formatted_data = {key: value.format(*format_args) for key, value in data.items()}
```

You can then re-encode the formatted data as JSON if need be.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 7, in <module>
  File "python", line 7, in <dictcomp>
IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: I edited the answer to prevent the error above.  It was missing a `*` to make a *reference* to the array for format values.

Comment: @LS Good catch, although the `*` has nothing to do with the reference/value distinction.  It just expands the list to positional arguments.  See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building these strings yourself or have control over them, have a different format be sent, or build the value as a dictionary and use `json.dumps`.

However, if you really need to do this, if it's guaranteed that the substitution values will be in the format `{X}`, then you can escape the string with this kludge:

```
import re
s = '{"key1":{0}, "key2":{1}}'
begin = re.compile(r'{(?!\d)')
end = re.compile(r'(?<!\d)}')
escaped = end.sub('}}', begin.sub('{{', s))
print(escaped.format(1, 2))
```

results in

```
{"key1":1, "key2":2}
```

Note that this is not the best solution. Considering you have control of the strings, you should be escaping them in some other way. Maybe use the `%` syntax instead of `str.format`?

Comment: Your regular expression will fail when json string will like :
s = '{"key1":{0}, "key2":{1}, "key3":5}'
So 'end' should be like following (I am not sure so I am not editing the answer)
end = re.compile(r'(?<!{\d)}')

Answer (score 0):

You can use another formatting method:

```
'{"key1":"%s", "key2":"%s"}' % ("value1", "value2")
```